# Use the difference quotient to compute a formula in terms of h

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Using the difference quotient: $\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$,

I need to compute a formula in terms of $h$, given $f(x)$ and $x$, ensuring that the $h$ in the denominator gets cancelled out.

Given an equation $f(x)$ (e.g. $f(x)=2x^2+3$) and a value for $x$ (e.g. $x=1$), how would I go about doing this?

Comment: [how to format a question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case:

$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{2(x+h)^2-2x^2}{h}\\
=2\frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h}\\
=2\frac{x^2+h^2+2hx-x^2}{h}\\
=2\frac{h^2+2hx}{h}\\
=2\frac{h(h+2x)}{h}\\
=2(h+2x)
$$

Now just substitute wathever value of $x$ you want.

Note that for some $f(x)$ there are different ways of computing what you wanted and methods vary. So there's no general formula that would drop $h$ from the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you *shouldn't* start with a specific value for $x$. What you need to do is calculate the difference quotient, as given by the formula.

A good place to start would be to calculate $f(x+h),$ which would be $2(x+h)^2+3,$ in your example. You may need to work it out one piece at a time, expanding $(x+h)^2,$ then distributing the $2,$ then adding the $3,$ for example.

Next, you'll want to subtract $f(x)$ from your result. If everything has been done correctly up to that point, everything left after this subtraction will have a factor of $h$ that we can pull out.

Finally, divide the result of the subtraction by $h$, which should be fairly easy, if we've already pulled out the $h$ factor.

At that point, you're done! You now have a formula into which we can substitute specific values for $x$ and $h$.

For a general approach that applies to a family of fairly familiar functions (though not to all functions), you can adapt the method I describe in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/195882/28900), using $x+h$ instead of $x,$ and using $x$ instead of $x_0.$